# Adaptation of sticky script

Tags: sticky

After a good deal of searching I can't seem to find answer that suits my needs. While working on a satirical blog project (located [here](http://whitesladiesnights.blogspot.com)) I was able to get a sticky sidebar to work on the right sidebar, stopping nicely at the top as planned. Formerly the left sidebar was modelled to do the same, which it did. What I'm after is using a similar setup to have a second element, further down the page in the left sidebar, or the right, follow the first as it scrolls out view, and stop at the top similarly, some parameter which allows flexibility in having content further down stop at the top. Either this isn't possible, or my skill-set isn't such that I just don't know what I'm doing (very likely the later) and I would be eternally indebted for guidance. Below you will find the existing coding used (left as is to demonstrate the issue as is on the linked page but obviously incorrect in context). I can't imagine I'm the only one who's after this variation, and if a solution is provided, it will be gratefully and duly notated in the script accordingly. My CSS knowledge is slightly better than rudimentary, but specifics would greatly appreciated. I imagine some further positioning is needed. Happy to provide additional insight to the generous soul who responds if needed. Currently the elements to which this applied are accurate (i.e. ".sidebar-right-1" and "HTML7" respectively)…

```
#sidebar-right-1.sticky {
position: fixed;
width: 310px;
top: 5px
}
#HTML7.sticky {
position: fixed;
width: 310px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -690px;
top:5px
```

And the corresponding script below

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
var offset = 0;
var sticky = false;
var top = $(window).scrollTop();
if ($("aside").offset().top < top) {
$("#sidebar-right-1, #HTML7").addClass("sticky");
sticky = true;
} else {
$("#sidebar-right-1, #HTML7").removeClass("sticky");
}
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Cheers, and kindly forgive any etiquette oversights herein.